# Spark Job Scheduling Running 2 jobs Concurrently

Tags: apache-spark, job-scheduling

I wonder how do you run two jobs currently, at the moment I try to run spark jobs, and it just won't run more than one job, the other job status would be accepted but not running until the current running job is failed/completed.

I tried using `conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR”)`so that it won't do FIFO, but still does not work the way i thought it would be

Comment: Do you have resources to run the other job?

Comment: Yes out of 40GB of RAM only 7GB is used. so there were plenty of resource  to run another job. @YuvalItzchakov